# Is a linear closed and everywhere defined operator bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A \colon X \to X$ be a linear operator. ($D(A) = X$) Prove of disprove that if $A$ is closed then it is necessarly bounded.
(I'm having troubles in finding a connection between closedness and boundedness)

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What do you mean by closed? If it's that the graph is closed, then it follows from a well-known theorem.

Comment: This is the Closed Graph Theorem, which is a quick consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem applied to the map $x \to (x,Ax)$ from $X$ to $X \times X$.

Comment: Thank you both, I do not know why I did not figure it out! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

A partially defined linear operator $A \colon D(A) \subset X \to Y$ is called *[closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators)* if and only if its graph $\{(x,Ax) \mid x \in D(A)\}$ is closed in $X \times Y$.

Now $D(A) = X = Y$ are assumed to be Banach spaces, so you can apply the [closed graph theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem).